# php array return

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

Ok, function:

```
function session_login_name($username) {
                global $myDB;
                global $config;
                $query = "SELECT /* page == login, functions.php */id, username FROM members WHERE username = '".$username."' LIMIT 1";
                $result = $myDB->Execute($query) or die(GetDbError($myDB->ErrorMsg()));
                $nick_show = $result->Fields("username");
                $nick_id = $result->Fields("id");
                $arr = array($nick_show, $nick_id);
                return $arr;
}
```

In next file i need describe:

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = ;   //user id
$_SESSION['username'] = ; //user name
```

How do I do that?
If question unclear, just say it...
Oh, and print_r ($arr) gives: Array ( [0] => zero [1] => 4 )

I have tried (guessed), but that of course isn't correct :/

```
echo session_login_name($username[0]);
die();
```

Comment: Beware of the user called `evil'; drop table members; --`

Comment: `WHERE username = '".$username."'` you're not sanitizing the username string which can lead to `bad` things, see @Denis' comment

Comment: escaping done in above part: if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said `print_r ($arr) gives: Array ( [0] => zero [1] => 4 )` so you just need to get those value and assign them to the session variables:

```
// ToDo: fix SQL injection vulnerability in your SQL
$Data = session_login_name($username);
$_SESSION['userid'] = $Data[1];   //user id
$_SESSION['username'] = $Data[0]; //user name
```

Comment: Thanks, the correct would be: $data = session_login_name($username);
echo $data[0];
die();

Answer (score 0):

```
$nick_show = $result->Fields("username");
$nick_id = $result->Fields("id");
$arr['userid'] = $nick_id;   //user id
$arr['username'] = $nick_show; //user name
return $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

well you cant echo an array  it will print array() on the screen

where did you define $username ?

well simply read the values of the array

Comment: you could've posted this as a comment instead

Comment: well there is no "add comment" on this post for me ^^

Comment: i see you're not priviledged just yet. apologies.